# Zsh runs precmd after I run a command

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

For some reason, zsh's `precmd` runs *after* commands instead of before them...?

```
[user@main ~/workspace]$ cat ~/workspace/precmd.sh
echo "Command should start after this line, but it will not"
[user@main ~/workspace]$ precmd () { ~/workspace/precmd.sh }
[user@main ~/workspace]$ command -v vim
/usr/bin/vim
Command should start after this line, but it will not
```

I've tried using `trap '/home/user/workspace/precmd.sh' DEBUG` in my zshrc but that does not work either.

Answer (score 5):

That's how it's meant to be, even if the name of the function¹ may be a bit misleading.

`precmd` is executed before each prompt. It's similar to `bash`'s `$PROMPT_COMMAND`²

From `info zsh precmd`:

> `precmd`
>
> Executed before each prompt.  Note that precommand functions are
> not re-executed simply because the command line is redrawn, as
> happens, for example, when a notification about an exiting job is
> displayed.

For something executed before each command, see the `DEBUG` trap³.

And for something executed before starting interpreting the code you have entered at the prompt (upon pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>), see the `preexec` hook function.

```
prompt$ precmd() echo precmd; preexec() print -r preexec $1; TRAPDEBUG() print -r debug $ZSH_DEBUG_CMD
debug echo precmd
precmd
prompt$ echo 1; echo 2; echo 3
debug print -r preexec $1
preexec echo 1; echo 2; echo 3
debug echo 1
1
debug echo 2
2
debug echo 3
3
debug echo precmd
precmd
prompt$
```

See also the `debugbeforecmd` option that decides whether DEBUG traps are run before (default) or after commands.

Instead of setting the `precmd`/`preexec` functions, you can also define your own function and add it to the corresponding `precmd_functions` / `preexec_functions` array (there's no equivalent for traps):

```
myhook() echo myhook
precmd_functions+=(myhook)
```

See also [`zsh-add-hook`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-add_002dzsh_002dhook)

---

<sup>¹ that `precmd` name comes from `tcsh` which had a similar feature, added there circa 1983 by Karl Kleinpaste according to early changelogs. zsh had `precmd` in its initial 1.0 release already in 1990.</sup>

<sup>² added there very early in `bash` development. Was already there in 1.02 in 1989</sup>

<sup>³ from the Korn shell in the 80s. Also in the first version of zsh in 1990.</sup>

Comment: Looks like `preexec ()` was what I wanted, not `precmd ()`. Thanks.